# Find out class etc. of object that another class was instantiated within as an attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is an example of what I'm trying to do, using Python 3:

If an `owner` method of a `wheel` object, that is part of a `car` object were to return its owner's name - which in this case should be the same as the `car` owner - how would it access the `car` object's `owner` attribute in Python?

The structure is as follows:

```
object car
- has: owner attribute
- has: owner getter method
- has: list of wheel objects
-- contains: wheel object
--- has: owner getter method
```

What I want to (edit: must) avoid, is providing the `car` object as a parameter (`self`) to the constructor when instantiating the `wheel` object.
Meaning: The `wheel` object should make itself aware of the context / `car` class object it is being instantiated within and keep a reference to it.

How do I do that?

Example code might look like:

```py
    class car:
      def __init__(self):
        self.owner = "testowner"
        self.wheels = list()
        self.wheels.append(wheel())    # wheel must not be called with "self" as a parameter

      def get_owner(self):
        return self.owner

    class wheel:
      def __init__(self):
         self.car_mounted_to = self.get_instantiating_object()    # the object "mycar" in this example

      def get_instantiating_object(self):
        # ... ? ...

      def get_owner(self):
        self.car_mounted_to.get_owner()

    mycar = car()
    mycar.wheels.append(wheel())    # this should still result in the object "mycar"
```

Comment: *"What I want to avoid, is providing the car object as a parameter (self) to the constructor when instantiating the wheel object"* – Yeah, no, don't think up some magic. *Explicitly* passing the dependency around is the only realistic way.

Comment: "What I want to avoid, is providing the car object as a parameter (self) to the constructor when instantiating the wheel object. Meaning: The wheel object should make itself aware of the context / car class object it is being instantiated within and keep a reference to it." Why **why** do you want to avoid that? That is the sane, straight-forward way.

Comment: Now that I look at it, I'm considering to make use of a tree structure, implementing the Composite design pattern, and traversing it up to a parent / component of class "car" ... detaching my application needs from the language abilities.

Comment: And why does that mean you don't want to pass the car object as a parameter to the wheel constructor?

Comment: To clarify: The implicit nature really is an absolute must.
In this simplified example it seems like a good idea to just provide that one object reference ... however, in the actual use case, there is even more nesting going on and then I'd need to provide a whole palette of object references. As soon as the car is wrapped in another container, I would even need to rewrite the whole thing, which I want to avoid.
The object knows where it's situated, so logically follows that it can retrieve the containers' information on its own.

Comment: You can use a “nested structure” and then have external code traverse that structure and know the position of every object. If you want objects to be “self aware”, you’ll need to give them the information explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

A wheel can only know it’s a wheel, it can’t know what structure it is a part of. Since the wheel is an object that can be passed around, it’s possible for the wheel to be part of more than one structure at once. Typically you don’t want objects to know too much about their “surroundings”, as that creates needless dependencies and makes objects more complex and brittle than need be. An object should only know about things that it received as constructor or method arguments and not try to infer anything about its environment.

I see two possible approaches:

1. Create your car object and give it wheel objects, but don’t make the wheels aware of the car at all. You then have some *external* code that traverses your object hierarchy, and while doing so it will discover the wheels on the car and hence know what belongs to what.
2. Implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and any time you try to access a wheel of the car, the car object will return a “bound” wheel in some way or another (e.g. like methods receive `self` as their first argument). So the car object is still being passed to the wheel explicitly (since that’s the only sane way to make the wheel aware of the car), but it happens not at construction time but when you access the specific car’s wheel. That also solves the problem of possibly assigning one wheel to another car and messing up the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the following could be a solution that meets your demand: We keep track of all `cars`, so we can find the `car` a certain `wheel` is mounted on by checking every `car` whether the wheel is mounted on it.

NB that this is far away from straight forward of implementing what you need. You should very well know why you do it that way and not just simply have the `car_mounted_on` as an instance variable of `wheel`. That said, if you really know why and want to do this, this is how it could be done:

```
import typing


class Car:
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, wheels: typing.List["Wheel"], owner: "Person"):
        Car.instances.append(self)
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.owner = owner


class Wheel:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def car_mounted_on(self) -> typing.Union["Car", None]:
        for car in Car.instances:
            if self in car.wheels:
                return car

    @car_mounted_on.setter
    def car_mounted_on(self, car: "Car"):
        # Remove the wheel from its current car and mount it on the given car.
        self.car_mounted_on.wheels.remove(self)
        car.wheels.append(self)

    @property
    def owner(self):
        if self.car_mounted_on is not None:
            return self.car_mounted_on.owner
```